# Update list of object from another list lambda expressions in java 8

Tags: java, list, object, lambda, stream

I have 2 Lists of object. The object is simple class contains key,value attributes.
I want to update the value of the first list from the second one.
Replacing or cloning the list is not working because the ordering of the two lists are different and they should stay in their orders.
Any suggestion.

example:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < mValues.size() ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < mValues.size() ; j++)
            {
                if(newData.get(i).getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(mValues.get(j).getKey()))
                {
                    mValues.get(j).setValue(newData.get(i).getValue());
                }
            }

        }
```

Demo:

```
myObject o1 = new myObject("k1" , 10);
myObject o2 = new myObject("k2" , 20);
myObject o3 = new myObject("k2" , 30);
myObject o4 = new myObject("k1" , 40);

List<myObject> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<myObject> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
l1.add(o1);
l1.add(o2);

l2.add(o3);
l2.add(o4);
```

Here should make the update to l1 based on l2 by looking for the key and update the value.
The result should look like:

```
l1 key is "k1" and value is 40 and next key is "k2" and the value is 30
```

Comment: Unclear what you want. Please rephrase the question and show an example.

Comment: @akuzminykh I added an example

Comment: are you using a hashmap?

Comment: @beastlyCoder no, I am using list

Comment: have you tried using the addAll() method

Comment: Do addAll respect the order of the first list ? I dont want to lost the order of the first list.

Comment: look at my solution as reference

Comment: this may be better suited for a hashmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use streams for that job.

Assuming your class `MyObject` has getters and setters methods defined (`getKey()`, `getValue()`, `setKey()`, `setValue()`), you can do:

```
l1.forEach(myObject1 -> l2.stream()
            .filter(myObject2 -> myObject1.getKey().equals(myObject2.getKey()))
            .findAny().ifPresent(myObject2 -> myObject1.setValue(myObject2.getValue())));
```

If you can have duplicate keys then you should modify `ifPresent()` to `forEach()`:

```
l1.forEach(myObject1 -> l2.stream()
            .filter(myObject2 -> myObject1.getKey().equals(myObject2.getKey()))
            .forEach(myObject2 -> myObject1.setValue(myObject2.getValue())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not many elegant one line streaming I can think of. My suggestion is split two steps:

1. convert `l2` to map.
2. stream map change items in `l1`.
   This is more flexible and easy to debug solution.

```
static class myObject {
    String key;
    int val;

    public myObject(String key, int val) {
      this.key = key;
      this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "myObject{" +
          "key='" + key + '\'' +
          ", val=" + val +
          '}';
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    myObject a = new myObject("k1", 30);
    myObject b = new myObject("k2", 40);
    Map<String, myObject> list2map = List.of(a,b).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.key, m -> m));

    myObject c = new myObject("k1", 10);
    myObject d = new myObject("k2", 20);
    List<myObject> l1 = List.of(c, d);
    l1 = l1.stream().map(m -> {
      m.val = list2map.getOrDefault(m.key, m).val;
      return m;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(l1);
  }
```